# How to fix memory leak with React Native ScreenStackFragment

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have been profiling Android app developed using React Native and found similar stack trace from the heap dump. However, since I am new to React Native not able to get my head around any probable fix till now. Could I get some help please!

Following is the stack trace in general

```
4086 bytes retained by leaking objects
Displaying only 1 leak trace out of 2 with the same signature
Signature: 40af8a997b87530c5a5a9802b690a5c657fe98a4
┬───
│ GC Root: Global variable in native code
│
├─ com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 5.5 kB in 221 objects
│    ↓ JavaModuleWrapper.mModuleHolder
│                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 52 B in 2 objects
│    ↓ ModuleHolder.mModule
│                   ~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 911.2 kB in 22002 objects
│    mReactApplicationContext instance of com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext, wrapping global.fwd.omne.MainApplication
│    ↓ UIManagerModule.mUIImplementation
│                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 661.2 kB in 14099 objects
│    mReactContext instance of com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext, wrapping global.fwd.omne.MainApplication
│    ↓ UIImplementation.mOperationsQueue
│                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 393.7 kB in 6061 objects
│    mReactApplicationContext instance of com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext, wrapping global.fwd.omne.MainApplication
│    ↓ UIViewOperationQueue.mNativeViewHierarchyManager
│                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 393.3 kB in 6052 objects
│    ↓ NativeViewHierarchyManager.mTagsToViews
│                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.util.SparseArray instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 386.7 kB in 6036 objects
│    ↓ SparseArray.mValues
│                  ~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 383.7 kB in 6034 objects
│    ↓ Object[37]
│            ~~~~
├─ com.swmansion.rnscreens.Screen instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 1.5 kB in 23 objects
│    View not part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext, wrapping activity global.fwd.omne.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ Screen.fragment
│             ~~~~~~~~
╰→ com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackFragment instance
     Leaking: YES (Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
     Retaining 2.0 kB in 69 objects
```

I have found out several discussions or old proposed fixes (already there in code base) such as

- https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens#android
- https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/17
- https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7078

But none of them is helpful.

- RN version: Latest
- Android Version: I used 12